# If statement shorthand for determining if multiple variables exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a shorthand for the following:

```
if ((items.length > 0) && ($item.length > 0)) {

    // Do Something...

}
```

Comment: How much shorter do you want it?

Comment: `if (items.length && $items.length)`?

Comment: Something like: (items && item).length)

Comment: @Vega: That's probably as short as you're gonna get it :)

Comment: `items.length + $items.length > 0`? assuming length cant be negative

Comment: If (item.length && $item.length) ?

Comment: @megawac: What if `items.length` is 1 and `$items.length` is 0?

Comment: @webbydevy: *"Something like: (items && item).length)"* How? You have two different identifiers in your question: `items` and `$item`.

Comment: if you know that the array values won't be falsy, if(items[0] && item$[0]) is slightly shorter than length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Below is under the assumption that `items` and `$items` are arrays**

Just use `items.length` which will be true for `> 0`

```
if (items.length && $items.length)
```

Comment: Technically this doesn't check if it's greater than `0`. Could make a difference, not knowing what the objects are.

Comment: @BlueSkies: I'm assuming they are arrays and I'm also assuming `length` won't be less than 0.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Right, that's my point. One must make those assumptions. Hard to say without more info, but probably pretty likely.

Answer (score 2):

You can drop the > 0 and use the truthy nature since 0 is false.

```
if (items.length && $item.length) {
```